# How to retrieve the new integer data after completion of a call to Document().Set(MapFieldValue{string_key, Increment()}) in Firestore C++

Tags: c++, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, atomic

I'm attempting to atomically increment integer values in Firestore and read the value on the client side after the Set() operation is complete on the server side, with the guarantee that another Set() call won't overwrite the value on the server before the value is retrieved for the client. Without this guarantee it seems that there could be a chance of unwanted data duplication.

However, I can't seem to find a means to guarantee this in my code.

Here's what I've written so far:

```
doc_ref.Get().OnCompletion([this, ref_name](const firebase::Future<firebase::firestore::DocumentSnapshot>& future) {
    if (future.error() == 0) {
        const firebase::firestore::DocumentSnapshot& document = *future.result();

        db->Collection("collection_name").Document(ref_name).Set({ ref_name, firebase::firestore::FieldValue::Increment(1) })
            .OnCompletion([this, ref_name](const firebase::Future<void>& void_future) {
            dr_uc.Get().OnCompletion([this, ref_name](const firebase::Future<firebase::firestore::DocumentSnapshot>& new_future) {

                if (new_future.error() == 0) {
                    const firebase::firestore::DocumentSnapshot& new_document = *new_future.result();
                    int user_name_count = new_document.Get(ref_name).integer_value();
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

The call to firebase::firestore::FieldValue::Increment(1) guarantees that the integer value will be updated atomically on the server side but the Get() call doesn't appear to guarantee a read from the server which hasn't been written to by another Set() call prior to the data being retrieved.

Is there some means to provide this guarantee using Firebase's Firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The increment operator does nothing more than ensure the increment happens atomically on the server, and does not involve any transfer of values to/from the client.

If you want full control over the order of the operations, including the read, you probably want to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to accomplish that.